# How to change displayed content in ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I use uigrid in my angulrjs project:

Here is content to display:

```
   $scope.arr = [{id:'124',name:'Max',  IsMale:'true'}, 
                  {id:'589',name:'Anna', IsMale:'false'}, 
                  {id:'45',name:'Donna', IsMale:'false'},
                  {id:'567',name:'Mark', IsMale:'true'}];
```

Here is UI-GRID defenition:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: false,
        enableToopTip: true,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            gridApi = gridApi
        }
    }

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'Name ', field: 'name', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true },
    { name: 'Id ', field: 'id', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true },
    { name: 'IsMail ', field: 'IsMale', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true }];

     $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.arr;
```

Here is template:

```
 <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2gum20bQw95t3P135jRa?p=preview).

I want to change displayed content of the `IsMal` field in ui-grid where the filed shows "true" I need to display "Yes" and  where is false I need to display "No".

Any ides how can I change the displayed content in ui-grid field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your $scope.arr so your isMale is actually a boolean type.

```
 $scope.arr = [{id:'124',name:'Max',  IsMale:true}, 
              {id:'589',name:'Anna', IsMale:false}, 
              {id:'45',name:'Donna', IsMale:false},
              {id:'567',name:'Mark', IsMale:true}];
```

And then I added a cellTemplate to your gridOptions.

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'IsMail ', field: 'IsMail', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, cellTemplate: '<div><p ng-if="COL_FIELD">YES</p><p ng-if="!COL_FIELD">NO</p></div>' }];
```

Comment: Can you post plunker? I cant make your solution work!